# Ocamlopt doesn’t produce any output, only an error code

Tags: c++, ocaml, interop, ffi

I’m trying to call into a bulky C++ library from OCaml, and I’m having trouble with ocamlopt, which sitently fails with error code 2.

I’m doing the whole dance with putting up a C interface, and I can get it to work in general, but as soon as I reference this library, build breaks.

Is there some way to know what exactly is failing? I tried the -verbose flag, but it just prints the commandline arguments (which are quite long).

Would you have any tips as to how to investigate a silent failure like this?

Comment: It might help if you named the system you're using (Linux, MacOS, Windows) and included some lines showing the error you're seeing. The term "error code" isn't particularly clear. It would be extremely strange for ocamlopt (or any serious program really) to call `exit(2)` without writing an explanatory message first. Maybe the error message is ending up somewhere out of the way.

Comment: It’s CentOS Linux. There’s no output, that’s why I’m at a loss for what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this again: the problem was that there were too many `-ccopt` and `-cclib` arguments getting passed in by the build driver. When I started including a C++ library with lots of other dependencies, we seemed to have reached the breaking point.

The solution was to change the build driver's OCaml compiler and linker rules to write all the compiler and linker args into files so they could all be passed in as a single `-ccopt @<compiler.args>` or `-cclib @<linker.args>` argument. Both `gcc` and [`ld` support the `@file` command line option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).

GitHub issue: [ocamlopt lets the compiler/linker silently fail if too many -ccopt or -cclib arguments are passed in](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/issues/8549)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR; check that you have enough memory and/or disk space.

Something like this could happen when `ocamlopt` is either killed by a signal or runs out the memory (or both), check the `dmesg` output, look for OOM messages from the kernel, also use `htop` to get the idea on the memory footprint.

Also, since this happens when you're trying to link with the C++ library, it is most likey that it is the `ld` process which is failing (again, most likely with OOM), as `ocamlopt` uses the system linker.

Comment: Ah, `dmesg` didn't tell me anything, but I tried `strace ld` and found this: `write(2, "ld", 2ld)                       = 2
write(2, ": no input files\n", 17: no input files
)      = 17`

Comment: that was a good idea to use `strace`! So, we have three problems here
1) you don't see the output - it might be a bug in the compiler, but as far as I know, it uses `system(2)` to call the system linker without any redirections (`strace dup` may prove me wrong). So most likely it is your build system that redirects stderr somewhere. 
2) the compiler is not doing enough sanitization of input, letting the linker fail.
3) most likely you're using `ocamlopt` somehow wrong (and definitely not in an expected manner).

Comment: The solutions are, for (1), if it is valid, submit an issue to github.com/ocaml/ocaml. For (2) submit a feature request at the same location. For (3) submit a question to SO, or just update yours, so we can figure out what is wrong with your invocation. If anything, otherwise we need to submit yet another issue to the OCaml issue tracker.

Comment: I think my build system is generating a command that’s too long. I tried putting (escapes) new lines after each -ccopt (most of them are -I with a directory search path), and I determined the point at which the number of args is too great (after all, my little program doesn’t need all those headers that come from the dependencies). Once I move past the compiler error, thoug, I still have a problem with the linker proper (too many -cclib args), since the linker actually does need all the dependencies. At this point, I’m feeling pretty discouraged :(

Comment: One thing I want to try tomorrow is giving a @file argument to gcc to see if it can deal with the arguments that way. I haven’t looked into whether ld has something similar.

Comment: Ok, I just confirmed that ld also takes a @file option, so that’s promising.